# cannot handle matrix/array columns with write.dbf

Tags: r, gis, spatial, shapefile, dbf

hope i get everything together for this problem. first time for me and it's a little bit tricky to describe.

I want to add some attributes to a dbf file and save it afterwards for use in qgis. its about elections and the data are the votes from the 11 parties in absolute and relative values. I use the shapefiles package for this, but also tried it simply with foreign.

my system: RStudio 0.97.311, R 2.15.2, shapefile 0.7, foreign 0.8-52, ubuntu 12.04

try #1 => no problems

```
shpDistricts <- read.shapefile(filename)
shpDataDistricts <- shpDistricts$dbf[[1]]
shpDataDistricts <- shpDataDistricts[, -c(3, 4, 5)] # delete some columns
shpDistricts$dbf[[1]] <- shpDataDistricts
write.shapefile(shpDistricts, filename))
```

try #2 => "error in get("write.dbf", "package:foreign")(dbf$dbf, out.name) :  cannot handle matrix/array columns"

```
shpDistricts <- read.shapefile(filename)
shpDataDistricts <- shpDistricts$dbf[[1]]
shpDataDistricts <- shpDataDistricts[, -c(3, 4, 5)] # delete some columns
shpDataDistricts <- cbind(shpDataDistricts, votesDistrict[, 2]) # add a new column
names(shpDataDistricts)[5] <- "SPOE"
shpDistricts$dbf[[1]] <- shpDataDistricts
write.shapefile(shpDistricts, filename))
```

the write function returns "error in get("write.dbf", "package:foreign")(dbf$dbf, out.name) :  cannot handle matrix/array columns"

so by simply adding a column (integer) to the data.frame, the write.dbf function isn't able to write out anymore. am now debugging for 3 hours on this simple issue. tried it with shapefiles package via opening shapefile and dbf file, all the time the same problem.

When i use the foreign package directly (read.dbf).

if i save the dbf-file without the voting data (only with the small adapations from step 1+2), it's no problem. It must have to do with the merge with the voting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error message ("error in get("write.dbf"...) while working with shapefiles in R using rgdal. I added a column to the shapefile, then tried to save the output and got the error. I was added the column to the shapefile as a dataframe, **when I converted it to a factor via as.factor() the error went away**.

shapefile$column <- as.factor(additional.column)

writePolyShape(shapefile, filename)

Comment: in my case it was a variable type problem too. wanted to write array variables instead of numeric. converted the columns and it worked. thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that write.dbf cannot write a dataframe into an attribute table. So I try to changed it to character data**.

My initial **wrong code** was:

```
d1<-data.frame(as.character(data1))
colnames(d1)<-c("county") #using rbind should give them same column name
d2<-data.frame(as.character(data2))
colnames(d2)<-c("county")
county<-rbind(d1,d2)
dbfdata$county <- county
write.dbf(dbfdata, "PANY_animals_84.dbf") **##doesn't work** 
##Error in write.dbf(dataname, ".bdf")cannot handle matrix/array columns
```

Then I changed everything to character, it works! **right code** is:

```
d1<-as.character(data1)
d2<-as.character(data2)
county<-c(d1,d2)
dbfdata$county <- county
write.dbf(dbfdata, "filename")
```

Hope it helps!